# How to add margins between columns in Bootsrap4?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I try to arrange 3 sections columns equally by assigning either col-lg-4 or col-lg-3 for each of them with Bootsstrap 4.

With col-lg-4 or any responsive combination that takes total of 12 columns, I get no margin between the columns.

With col-lg-3 the margins become too wide.

The same problem arises with both "container" and "container-fluid" class.

I tried also to adjust the margins manually, replacing mx-auto with Bootstrap4 margin set at m-3, but it does not solve the problem because in that case all the columns move to the left, leaving empty space on the right side of the screen.

The problem arises the moment I try to put margins. Otherwise, if there are no margins I can set col-lg-4 without a problem. I will get for instance 3 nice columns. But once I put margins, it becomes wrong. I followed the recommendation on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/ but still it does not help.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  }

 .navbar {
    background-color: rgb(178, 238, 13);
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  #collapsibleNavbar {
    background-color: rgb(229, 243, 192);
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .navbar-nav li a {
    color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
  }

  .navbar-brand {
      color: black; 
      padding: 15px;
  }

  h5{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding-top: 7px;
  }

  h2{
    font-size: 175%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }

  .paraf{
    background-color: #e6ee9c;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Module 3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
            <a id="get-back" class="navbar-brand" href="#">Food, LLC</a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
                    <ul class="d-lg-none d-md-none navbar-nav">
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#chicken">Chicken</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#beef">Beef</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#sushi">Sushi</a>
                      </li> 
                    </ul>
                  </div>
    </nav>
    
        
</header>
<h2 class="text-center"> Our Menu </h2>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 paraf mx-auto">
<h5 class="text-center" id="chicken">Chicken</h5>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur felis ut venenatis tortor, nulla fringilla commodo eget ullamcorper
viverra nulla. Quis donec ultricies, in non eget ultricies ut wisi pede. Eget faucibus ligula lacinia, ligula risus quasi, 
vestibulum amet mattis mi sit egestas, a velit integer, feugiat lectus et. Ullamcorper ut lobortis est, consequat magnis,
donec lorem posuere sit ridiculus lacinia augue, morbi magna velit pellentesque a vestibulum arcu, in facilisi ultricies
dolor eu dolor quis. Nec eu libero, fermentum sagittis augue wisi wisi adipiscing. Est risus dapibus cursus, praesent
vivamus mattis est, ac euismod quis. Primis diam enim tortor fermentum, varius pede officia pellentesque nibh quam 
blandit, accumsan vestibulum interdum vivamus, iaculis wisi lacus sodales facilisi. Molestie accusantium, sed nisl
ratione eu euismod nulla ac, morbi aliquet. Lacus egestas. Purus sem fusce et id nibh mauris, luctus magnis diam morbi
enim, nunc iste, laoreet commodo in tortor lobortis. Congue suspendisse pellentesque eget, nibh pulvinar dolor donec
hac, quis diam at vehicula suspendisse. Eget commodo libero, tortor integer, nec integer, mauris eget iaculis nec
imperdiet dolor eros.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur felis ut venenatis tortor, nulla fringilla commodo eget ullamcorper
viverra nulla. Quis donec ultricies, in non eget ultricies ut wisi pede. Eget faucibus ligula lacinia, ligula risus quasi, 
vestibulum amet mattis mi sit egestas, a velit integer, feugiat lectus et. Ullamcorper ut lobortis est, consequat magnis,
donec lorem posuere sit ridiculus lacinia augue, morbi magna velit pellentesque a vestibulum arcu, in facilisi ultricies
dolor eu dolor quis. Nec eu libero, fermentum sagittis augue wisi wisi adipiscing. Est risus dapibus cursus, praesent
vivamus mattis est, ac euismod quis. Primis diam enim tortor fermentum, varius pede officia pellentesque nibh quam 
blandit, accumsan vestibulum interdum vivamus, iaculis wisi lacus sodales facilisi. Molestie accusantium, sed nisl
ratione eu euismod nulla ac, morbi aliquet. Lacus egestas. Purus sem fusce et id nibh mauris, luctus magnis diam morbi
enim, nunc iste, laoreet commodo in tortor lobortis. Congue suspendisse pellentesque eget, nibh pulvinar dolor donec
hac, quis diam at vehicula suspendisse. Eget commodo libero, tortor integer, nec integer, mauris eget iaculis nec
imperdiet dolor eros. <br> (End of Chicken section) <a href="#get-back">Back to Top</a></p></div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 paraf mx-auto">
<h5 class="text-center" id="beef">Beef</h5>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur felis ut venenatis tortor, nulla fringilla commodo eget ullamcorper
viverra nulla. Quis donec ultricies, in non eget ultricies ut wisi pede. Eget faucibus ligula lacinia, ligula risus quasi, 
vestibulum amet mattis mi sit egestas, a velit integer, feugiat lectus et. Ullamcorper ut lobortis est, consequat magnis,
donec lorem posuere sit ridiculus lacinia augue, morbi magna velit pellentesque a vestibulum arcu, in facilisi ultricies
dolor eu dolor quis. Nec eu libero, fermentum sagittis augue wisi wisi adipiscing. Est risus dapibus cursus, praesent
vivamus mattis est, ac euismod quis. Primis diam enim tortor fermentum, varius pede officia pellentesque nibh quam 
blandit, accumsan vestibulum interdum vivamus, iaculis wisi lacus sodales facilisi. Molestie accusantium, sed nisl
ratione eu euismod nulla ac, morbi aliquet. Lacus egestas. Purus sem fusce et id nibh mauris, luctus magnis diam morbi
enim, nunc iste, laoreet commodo in tortor lobortis. Congue suspendisse pellentesque eget, nibh pulvinar dolor donec
hac, quis diam at vehicula suspendisse. Eget commodo libero, tortor integer, nec integer, mauris eget iaculis nec
imperdiet dolor eros.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur felis ut venenatis tortor, nulla fringilla commodo eget ullamcorper
viverra nulla. Quis donec ultricies, in non eget ultricies ut wisi pede. Eget faucibus ligula lacinia, ligula risus quasi, 
vestibulum amet mattis mi sit egestas, a velit integer, feugiat lectus et. Ullamcorper ut lobortis est, consequat magnis,
donec lorem posuere sit ridiculus lacinia augue, morbi magna velit pellentesque a vestibulum arcu, in facilisi ultricies
dolor eu dolor quis. Nec eu libero, fermentum sagittis augue wisi wisi adipiscing. Est risus dapibus cursus, praesent
vivamus mattis est, ac euismod quis. Primis diam enim tortor fermentum, varius pede officia pellentesque nibh quam 
blandit, accumsan vestibulum interdum vivamus, iaculis wisi lacus sodales facilisi. Molestie accusantium, sed nisl
ratione eu euismod nulla ac, morbi aliquet. Lacus egestas. Purus sem fusce et id nibh mauris, luctus magnis diam morbi
enim, nunc iste, laoreet commodo in tortor lobortis. Congue suspendisse pellentesque eget, nibh pulvinar dolor donec
hac, quis diam at vehicula suspendisse. Eget commodo libero, tortor integer, nec integer, mauris eget iaculis nec
imperdiet dolor eros.<br>(End of Beef section) <a href="#get-back">Back to Top</a></p></div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 paraf mx-auto">
<h5 class="text-center" id="sushi">Sushi</h5>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur felis ut venenatis tortor, nulla fringilla commodo eget ullamcorper
viverra nulla. Quis donec ultricies, in non eget ultricies ut wisi pede. Eget faucibus ligula lacinia, ligula risus quasi, 
vestibulum amet mattis mi sit egestas, a velit integer, feugiat lectus et. Ullamcorper ut lobortis est, consequat magnis,
donec lorem posuere sit ridiculus lacinia augue, morbi magna velit pellentesque a vestibulum arcu, in facilisi ultricies
dolor eu dolor quis. Nec eu libero, fermentum sagittis augue wisi wisi adipiscing. Est risus dapibus cursus, praesent
vivamus mattis est, ac euismod quis. Primis diam enim tortor fermentum, varius pede officia pellentesque nibh quam 
blandit, accumsan vestibulum interdum vivamus, iaculis wisi lacus sodales facilisi. Molestie accusantium, sed nisl
ratione eu euismod nulla ac, morbi aliquet. Lacus egestas. Purus sem fusce et id nibh mauris, luctus magnis diam morbi
enim, nunc iste, laoreet commodo in tortor lobortis. Congue suspendisse pellentesque eget, nibh pulvinar dolor donec
hac, quis diam at vehicula suspendisse. Eget commodo libero, tortor integer, nec integer, mauris eget iaculis nec
imperdiet dolor eros.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur felis ut venenatis tortor, nulla fringilla commodo eget ullamcorper
viverra nulla. Quis donec ultricies, in non eget ultricies ut wisi pede. Eget faucibus ligula lacinia, ligula risus quasi, 
vestibulum amet mattis mi sit egestas, a velit integer, feugiat lectus et. Ullamcorper ut lobortis est, consequat magnis,
donec lorem posuere sit ridiculus lacinia augue, morbi magna velit pellentesque a vestibulum arcu, in facilisi ultricies
dolor eu dolor quis. Nec eu libero, fermentum sagittis augue wisi wisi adipiscing. Est risus dapibus cursus, praesent
vivamus mattis est, ac euismod quis. Primis diam enim tortor fermentum, varius pede officia pellentesque nibh quam 
blandit, accumsan vestibulum interdum vivamus, iaculis wisi lacus sodales facilisi. Molestie accusantium, sed nisl
ratione eu euismod nulla ac, morbi aliquet. Lacus egestas. Purus sem fusce et id nibh mauris, luctus magnis diam morbi
enim, nunc iste, laoreet commodo in tortor lobortis. Congue suspendisse pellentesque eget, nibh pulvinar dolor donec
hac, quis diam at vehicula suspendisse. Eget commodo libero, tortor integer, nec integer, mauris eget iaculis nec
imperdiet dolor eros.<br>(End of Sushi section) <a href="#get-back">Back to Top</a></p></div>
</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Can you suggest how to fix this and get margins between the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `mt-2` and `mb-2` in your class `col-md-3`.

Comment: Thanks for the consideration Irawan. That will help for col-md-3, but what to do for col-lg-4? The problem still occurs.

Comment: if you want spacing by column, you can add col-lg-12 in col-lg-4 so, <div class='col-lg-4'><div class='col-lg-12> your content 1</div></div> <div class='col-lg-4'><div class='col-lg-12> your content 2</div></div> <div class='col-lg-4'><div class='col-lg-12> your content 3</div></div>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the col-lg-4 while using padding so it would look like they're separated and come out as:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 px-1 (other classes...)">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 px-1 (other classes...)">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 px-1 (other classes...)">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the consideration Adel. That would work if the background is white. Unfortunately in my case the background of the column divs is colored and padding does not help.

Comment: You can just remove the color applied to the columns and create a container-fluid inside each column, that container would have the background-color applied to

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="col-lg-12">
 your content 1
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="col-lg-12">
your content 2
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="col-lg-12">
your content 3
</div>
</div>
```

so just add col-lg-12 in col-lg-4

Comment: Thanks Irawan. I will try this approach. As I need to make the page responsive to different sizes, what should I do if I want to add md and sm classes besides the lg class?